# Calling specialized function from other specialized one

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have an error

```
C2910: 'TEMPLATE_TEST::FuncTemplateTest::InnerFunc' : cannot be explicitly specialized,
```

while compiling the code below. There are two template functions, and both of them are specialized. When I remove the call to `InnerFunc` in the specialized outer one, everything works normally. So, where is the problem? (I'm using MS VS 2008.)

```
class FuncTemplateTest {

public:
    template<typename T>
    const int OuterFunc(const T& key) const;

private:
    template<typename T>
    const int InnerFunc(const T& key) const;
};

template<typename T>
inline const int FuncTemplateTest::OuterFunc(const T &key) const 
{
     std::cout<<"Outer template\n";
     return InnerFunc(key);
}

template<>
inline const int FuncTemplateTest::OuterFunc<std::string>(const std::string &key) const 
{
    std::cout<<"Outer special\n" << key << '\n';
    InnerFunc(key); //remove this line to compile!!!
    return 1;
}

template<typename T>
inline const int FuncTemplateTest::InnerFunc(const T &key) const
{
     std::cout << "Inner template\nTemplate key\n";
     return 0;
}   

template<>
inline const int FuncTemplateTest::InnerFunc<std::string>(const std::string &key) const
{
    std::cout << key << '\n';
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the cause of the problem is that you define an explicit specialization for `InnerFunc` after that particular specialization has already been used in the code for `OuterFunc`.

If you **move the definitions for `InnerFunc` before the definitions for `OuterFunc`**, you should be fine. (On GCC this indeed solved the problem.)

---

Separate note: The return type of your functions is `const int`, which is not incorrect, but also quite useless (`const` is ignored when fundamental data types are returned by copy).

Comment: @Aleksey_M Glad I could help, and welcome to Stackoverflow! If the answer provided the information you were looking for, please kindly "accept" it (that's done by clicking the "accept" symbol on its left).